# Show that $\left( \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i \right)^{\theta} \geq \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^{\theta}$ for any $\theta \geq 2$ and $a_i \geq 0$.

Tags: inequality, summation

When $\theta = 2,3,4 \ldots$, the result is trivial. I trust $\theta > 2$ this is also hold. But I do not know how to prove it. Could any one help me. Thanks!

Comment: The result is immediately held if you expand L.H.S. and only take some of terms

Comment: Just show it's true when $n=2$.  The general result follows.  Do you see how?